# All sales emails got same template. Magento 2

Tags: magento2, email, invoice

Problem look like title, when i change order status i always is sended same maile (default order item) when its need to send invoice or shipping mail. Is anyone know where i can check how is template choosen for this action or know how to repair this problem.

Change configuration in admin panel not working. Its only work when i edit template for "order" but still its sended for all status.

Thanks for help.

Comment: if you want to make a customized email template you can follow this instruction https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-customize-email-template-transactional-email-magento-2.html

Comment: You don't understand. There is no reason to create customized email template because i cant send default templates. For all sales emails is sended only "Order" email.